# Remove html elements from wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

I am trying to remove the default divs that are wrapped around with the Wordpress Social Login plugin.

This is what is output by default:

```
    <div class="wp-social-login-widget">

    <div class="wp-social-login-connect-with">{connect_with_caption}</div>

    <div class="wp-social-login-provider-list">

        <a class="wp-social-login-provider wp-social-login-provider-facebook">
            <img src="{provider_icon_facebook}" />
        </a>

        <a class="wp-social-login-provider wp-social-login-provider-google">
            <img src="{provider_icon_google}" />
        </a>

        <a class="wp-social-login-provider wp-social-login-provider-twitter">
            <img src="{provider_icon_twitter}" />
        </a>

    </div> <!-- / div.wp-social-login-connect-options -->

    <div class="wp-social-login-widget-clearing"></div>

</div> <!-- / div.wp-social-login-widget -->
```

I'd like to get rid of all the divs and classes associated with the anchors. So that I can style it using my own theme.

I have found the file that generates those tags - but don't want to directly edit the plugin file `wsl.auth.widgets.php` because when it's updated then I'll have to continuously change it, removing with css `display:none;` might be an option but I would prefer writing something in the functions.php file so that it's permanent.

I've seen this function which changes the anchors only not sure how to go about removing the divs as well.

```
    function wsl_use_fontawesome_icons( $provider_id, $provider_name, $authenticate_url )
{
   ?>
   <a 
      rel           = "nofollow"
      href          = "<?php echo $authenticate_url; ?>"
      data-provider = "<?php echo $provider_id ?>"
      class         = "wp-social-login-provider wp-social-login-provider-<?php echo strtolower( $provider_id ); ?>" 
    >
      <span>
         <i class="fa fa-<?php echo strtolower( $provider_id ); ?>"></i>
         Sign in with <?php echo $provider_name; ?>
      </span>
   </a>
<?php
}

add_filter( 'wsl_render_auth_widget_alter_provider_icon_markup', 'wsl_use_fontawesome_icons', 10, 3 );
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason to do it in that way? Because that plugin is giving **custom CSS** option in its setting. So you can use that for customization according to your theme.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner instead of creating new rules it'd be easier to wrap it around my existing classes. And saves over-writing some of the existing rules that they inherit.

Comment: As plugin author did not provide any filter, it is difficult to change it. Still you can ask same question in plugin's [forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-social-login). They will help or else they will provide filter in their release.